# Execute bash script using CygWin

Tags: cygwin

How do you execute a bash script using CygWin? I am trying execute a bash script as part of a build.xml. This is the code snippet,

```
<property name="cygwinpath" value="C:/cygwin/bin/"/>
<property name="script" value="D:/tomcatserverxml"/>


<exec dir="${cygwinpath}" executable="bash.exe">
    <arg value="${script}"/>    
</exec>
```

Comment: This looks correct. What isn't working? Do you get any error message?

Comment: I get this error message : BUILD FAILED
D:\build.xml:39: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot runprogram "bash.exe" (in directory "C:\cygwin\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message say that there is no `bash.exe` to be found in the `C:/cygwin/bin/` path.

You mention a "build.xml" so I assume that you are using Ant to do a build.

If you are using Ant from inside CygWin then you must use the CygWin conventions for paths. So you have to use simply `/bin/` as path for bash.

(In this convention `C:/foo/bar/` transalte to `/cygdrive/c/foo/bar/` but CygWin simulate a *nix like filesistem so there is a `/bin/` and a `/usr/bin/` (and so on) that point to the right places. Check CygWin docs: [Using Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html))

Do a simple check:

- into a CygWin terminal type the command `ls /bin/bash.exe` : it list the executable for bash
- open a windows CMD and type the command `dir C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe`: it list the executable for bash

If the second commad fail, probably CygWin is not installed in the standard path  `C:/cygwin/` so do check another path like `D:/cygwin/`.